# how to change bottom bar color in Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, xamarin

Can't change bottom bar color. How change? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shHt1.png)

Comment: There is no bottom bar there. This is just the background of your ViewController you can see down there.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you used a top margin instead of a safe area on iOS, then your bottom would be the same color as your page. But if you use safe area, then it will be white or black. I am also looking for a way to change it if I use safe area.